# Sourcetree git flow finish feature to develop branch but develop branch is protected

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I made a mistake.
In Sourcetree I created a new feature branch starting from develop and made some changes. Afterwards I wanted to finish the feature and delete the feature branch. Sadly I forgot that the develop branch is protected and needs at least one review before being allowed to commit to it. Also I don't have the rights to circumvent this.

Now my feature branch is deleted and my changes can't be pushed.

How can I revert my mistake and e.g. get the feature branch back (or creating a new one) and creating a pull request instead of just finishing it instead?

The (anonymized) graph looks something like this:
[image]

Error while pushing:
[image]

Comment: It's merged without problems but it can't be pushed. I'll edit it with a screenshot from the push error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you merged your feature branch into `dev` locally but you regret this and wish to perform the merge at the server side instead (by way of a pull request). No problem!

1. Create a new feature branch from the "Fix" commit and push it (and ask for pull request at GitHub).
2. Then hard reset your local `dev` to the commit before the merge (not shown in your screenshot), thus undoing the unwanted local merge.

   *Or, even better,* delete your local `dev` entirely! It serves no purpose, as you can never merge to it, and it leads you into errors like this one. To create a new branch in future, just fetch and then branch from `origin/dev`. That's what the professionals do!

(Both those things are quite easily done in Sourcetree, though personally I would use the command line.)